# Better Way to handle an ordered list of items?

Tags: php, javascript, web

I have list of items that need to be processed and printed to the user.

Each item on the list needs to have a unique set of calculations to it.

The only thing is, the user also supplies me with the order of how items will be printed & handled first - for example: item4,item2,item1,item3

How can one approach this in PHP?

I thought of running a for loop against the user submitted ordered list and tackle each calculation and print it to the user, the problem is that this will be hard to maintain because the user will have to edit the for loop each time he will want to add a new item or calculation.

Comment: Just clarifying: You need to apply different calculations to the different items in the list, so if the list was in the order "Potato,Carrot,Egg" you'll want to mash the potato, peel the carrot and boil the egg. On top of that, they might not be in that order (it might be "Carrot,Potato,Egg") but you still want to apply the appropriate calculation to each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of 1-n items:

```
$items['item1'] = $item1;
```

With a co-related list of 1-n functions:

```
$functions['item1'] = function($item) {return ...;};
```

You can sort items according to the user-input:

```
$subset = orderAndFilterItems($items, $userInput);
```

and then iterate:

```
foreach($subset as $key => $item)
{
    $function = $functions[$key];
    $value = $function($item);
}
```

Naturally you can encapsulate this further on, but it should give you the idea.